# How does python deal with built-in functions?

Tags: python, function, bytecode

`print('Hello World')`

When the above code is first compiled, does the bytecode contain the source code of `print` function? How does the Python interpreter get the source code of `print`?

Comment: There are *lots* of built-in functions in Python that are part of the underlying interpreter and don't need source.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Elaborate *underlying interpreter*.

Comment: If you look at the source for CPython for example you can see the functions in C form.

Comment: @NirajRaut Python is an interpreted language. It doesn't compile to executable code, it compiles to bytecode that runs in the Python interpreter (which must be installed on the running machine)

Comment: @Mark Ransom Okay, so the built-in python functions are basically a part of the CPython implementation, right?

Comment: @AdamSmith Python *implementations* may be either interpreters or compilers. The language itself doesn't specify one or the other. CPython is implemented as both: it compiles Python source to Python byte code, then interprets the byte code.

Comment: Not all of them, but many.  It's all implementation details anyway, your program won't care about the specifics of how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dis` module to see how CPython handles a builtin function.

```
$ cat tmp.py
print('Hello World')
$ python3 -m dis tmp.py
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello World')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The name of the function and its argument are loaded onto the stack, then `CALL_FUNCTION` takes care of looking up the name using the usual lookup algorithm. In the case of `print`, the name exists in the built-in scope, and the result of that lookup is an object provided by the Python implementation.

Other implementations may differ; the only real requirement is that `print('Hello World')` not raise a `NameError`, assuming something like `del print` is not used before the call, and that the resulting function call conform to the defined behavior of the built-in function.

Comment: Whoa, what? What's this `PRINT_ITEM` and `PRINT_NEWLINE` stuff? I thought that was Python 2 only.

Comment: Gah, forgot to type `python3` for that example. Hold on, I'll clean out the nonsense parts of the answer.

Comment: @chepner Are namespaces created in memory?